# Are there any plans to update curl package to its latest 8.4.0 version, for all ubuntu flavors?

Tags: curl

CVE-2023-38545 and CVE-2023-38546 have been flashed for cUrl/libcurl.

Are there any updates about the plan of updating curl package to its latest version of 8.4.0 for different ubuntu flavor's

Comment: Whichever affected versions of curl are packaged in Ubuntu will be patched with backported fixes. There's no way they will be updating to 8.4 (which is not packaged for any current version of Ubuntu). Just keep an eye on the Ubuntu CVE tracker for that CVE.

Comment: As of now, there is no entry yet. Debian security tracker has a better overview imo https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2023-38545